# Strongly continuous group on $H^{-1}$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, semigroup-of-operators

Let $U : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow H^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$ a strongly continous unitary group on $H^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$
In particular the map $t \in  \mathbb{R} \rightarrow U(t)\delta_{0} \in H^{-1}$ is continuous.

> Does the map : $$ t \in \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \langle U(t)\delta_{0},
>  \varphi \rangle $$ is continuous for $\varphi \in
>  C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) $ given ?

I think it's enough to show that if $\varphi \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) $ then $L_{\varphi} : T \in H^{-1} \rightarrow \langle T, \varphi \rangle $ is continuous.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: What exactly is $C_c^\infty$ in this context?  Does this mean that $\varphi$ is continuous with compact support?

Comment: It means $C^{\infty}$ with compact support indeed.

Comment: It would indeed be enough to show that $L_{\varphi}$ is continuous; because $L_{\varphi}$ is linear, it suffices to show that it is bounded.  However, I'm not sure how to show even this.  I think that the naive approach of using Holder's inequality on $\langle T,\varphi \rangle$ runs into trouble with the conditions that define $H^{-1}(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: What definition of $H^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$ are you working from?

Comment: We have $H^{-1}(\mathbb{R})= (H^{1}(\mathbb{R}))' = \{ u \in S'(\mathbb{R}) ; (1+|\xi|^{2})^{-\frac{1}{2}} \mathcal{F}(u)(\xi) \in L^{2} \} = \{ u \in D'(\mathbb{R}) ; |<T,\varphi>|\le C |\varphi|_{H^{1}(\mathbb{R})} \}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $T_n\to 0$ in $H^{-1}$, this means that

$$\|\mathcal F^{-1}([1+\xi^2]^{-1/2}\mathcal FT_n)\|_{L^2}\to0.$$
Since the Fourier transform is unitary on $L^2$ this is the same as $\int_{\Bbb R}\frac1{1+\xi^2}|\mathcal FT_n|^2\to0$ (with a big root symbol over the integral). In particular we can multiply with $\int_{\Bbb R}(1+\xi^2)|\mathcal F\varphi|$ ($\mathcal F\varphi$ is Schwartz) and what you get will still go to $0$. Now here you have a product of the form $\|X_n\|_{L^2}\cdot\|Y\|_{L^2}$, which by Cauchy inequality bounds $|\langle X_n, Y\rangle|$. This thing that is bounded is however equal to:

$$\int \frac1{(1+\xi^2)^{1/2}}(1+\xi^2)^{1/2} \overline{\mathcal FT_n}\,\mathcal F\varphi = \langle\mathcal FT_n,\mathcal F\varphi\rangle = \langle T_n,\varphi\rangle.$$
This gives you continuity.

Comment: For $T\in H^{-1}$ you have that $\mathcal F T\in L^2$ and that $\langle T, \varphi \rangle = \langle \mathcal F T ,\mathcal F \varphi\rangle$ by a property of the Fourier transform. Here the first bracket is duality, the second is also duality but both functions are now $L^2$ functions so its the same as the $L^2$ dot product. At least that is how I see what is happening, maybe I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: You are perfectly right. Thank you for your help. We can generalize the problem with $ t \rightarrow T_{t} \in C^{0}(\mathbb{R},D'(\mathbb{R}))$ so that's why I didn't expect to see that much $H^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$ in the solution.

Comment: Well it might depend on characterisation. On the one hand the map $L_x :X'\mapsto \Bbb K , f\mapsto f(x)$ is always continuous if $X'$ is given a topology finer than the weak topology. If you view $H^{-1}$ as a subspace of $D'$ where $D'$ has the appropriate topology then the statement is obvious without any more details. If you however say $H^{-1}$ is this space of functions with this norm, then more work should be necessary.